# R: how to use table to tabulate m x n data

Tags: r

```
mydat = data.frame(Q1 = c(0, 1, 0, 1), Q2 = c(0, 1, 1, 1), 
                   Q3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), Gender = c("M", "M", "F", "F"))
> mydat
  Q1 Q2 Q3 Gender
1  0  0  1      M
2  1  1  1      M
3  0  1  1      F
4  1  1  1      F

> table(mydat[,1:3], mydat$Gender)

Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

I have a very simple data set with 3 binary questions and a gender variable. I'm interested to see if there is any association between the 3 questions and gender, so I would like to tabulate my data into a 3 (questions) x 2 (gender) count table. I want my table to look something like this

```
      Q1    Q2    Q3
M      1     1     2
F      1     2     2
```

Edit:

```
mydat = data.frame(Q1 = c(0, 1, NA, 1), Q2 = c(0, 1, 1, 1), 
                   Q3 = c(1, NA, 1, 1), Gender = c("M", "M", "F", "F"))

> rowsum(mydat[1:3], mydat$Gender)
  Q1 Q2 Q3
F NA  2  2
M  1  1 NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a group by operation and `sum` the elements of other columns

```
library(dplyr)
mydat %>% 
   group_by(Gender) %>% 
   summarise_all(funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#   Gender    Q1    Q2    Q3
#   <fctr> <int> <int> <int>
#1      F     1     2     2
#2      M     1     1     2
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
rowsum(mydat[-4], mydat$Gender, na.rm = TRUE)
#   Q1 Q2 Q3
#F  1  2  2
#M  1  1  2
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a follow-up question, if my data set contains some `NA`s and I do not want those to affect my tabulation, what should I do?

Comment: @Adrian  In that case, use the `na.rm=TRUE` in `sum` i.e. `mydat %>% group_by(Gender) %>% summarise_all(funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))` and it can also be used in `rowsum`

Comment: Sorry, I have another question. Suppose I just want a 2x2 table of Q1 and Gender. `rowsum(mydat[1], mydat$Gender, na.rm = TRUE)` only gives me a 2x1 table.

Comment: @Adrian Perhaps you need `table` there i.e. `table(mydat[c('Q1', 'Gender')])`